# I have button in table view cell when I click the perticular index button state will change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellClassName = @"CarDriverTableViewCell";

    CarDriverTableViewCell *cell = (CarDriverTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellClassName];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CarDriverTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellClassName];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CarDriverTableViewCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    }

    UILabel *lbltime=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lbldriver=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lbllicence=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    bookbtn=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
   // [bookbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    lbltime.text=[[arrnames valueForKey:@"time"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lbldriver.text=[[arrnames valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lbllicence.text=[[arrnames valueForKey:@"license_plate"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    bookbtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [bookbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}
-(void)btnclicked:(id)sender
{
    [bookbtn setTitle:@"Pending" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

When I click particular index button then my button name will change and remaining cells will be select.

When I got response of button name as accept and reject then only my table view cells will be select.

Comment: Its not clear in your question. what do you want exactly? or what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: What exactly you want button selected or tableview cell and what is your requirement?

Comment: in my table view each cell containing one button.When i click that button my button title name will change and when we click remaining cells not select.  After got response from server (now button title name)will change and remaining cells enable to select

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    bookbtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [bookbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [yourtableview realoadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    bookbtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [bookbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     return bookbtn

}
```